# Change in getConnection Method Using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using getConnection method in my program and I want to restore the response in a variable like "String result " in-order to use in another class, but I don't know how I must change the method. Does anyone have an idea?.

```
public class Webservice {
 public static void getConnection(Context context, String url){

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("TEST", "Response is: "+ response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("TEST","That didn't work!");
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);

 }
}
```

Comment: try updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable in Application class and use it throughout your application like this

```
public class App extends android.app.Application {


   private static App instance;
   public static String resultResponse;

   public static App getInstance() {
    return instance;
   }



   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    instance = this;
   }  
}
```

Then when you get the response save it like this

```
 public class Webservice {
   public static void getConnection(Context context, String url){

   RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,    
   url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("TEST", "Response is: "+ response);
                App.getInstance().resultResponse = response;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("TEST","That didn't work!");
     }
  });
    queue.add(stringRequest);

 }
 }
```

Add

```
android:name = ".App"
```

in Application in your manifest.

Now Use

```
     App.getInstance().resultResponse
```

where ever you want through out your Application.

Comment: thanks,consider that I want to use in MainActivity.java  the response. I write like this : Webservice.readUrl(this, "http://192.168.1.36/note-server/");. but my method returns void , so I can't store it in any variable. can you tell me what should I do exactly ? @Abhishek Jaiswal

Comment: sry, but where is the response ? @Abhishek Jaiswal I want to store it in a variable such as result .

Comment: it was awesome , but I want to call the getConnection method like this:  String result =Webservice.getConnection(this,"192.168.1.36") . is that possible? @Abhishek Jaiswal

Comment: Since the method calls webservice you have to use callbacks(Interface) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface having return type String in onResponse method and implement this interface in your required class get String response.